Type Error: 'type' object is subscriptable
Написал в VS Code:
digits: list[int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0] 
print(digits)

Компилятор:

Type Error: 'type' object is subscriptable

Отладил код, но ничего не понял.

Компилятор попытался вычислить выражение list[int] , не смог.  Подозреваю, разные версии питонов в отладчике VSCode / интерпретаторе / компиляторе.

Надо так:
from typing import List
digits: List[int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]


Возможность использовать list (и других стандартных типов) в параметризованных (с квадратными скобками) аннотациях появилась начиная с Python 3.9, см. PEP-585 (он как раз про использование стандартных коллекций list, set, dict и т.д. в качестве аннотаций).
На более старых версиях используйте List из стандартного модуля typing.
Правильны оба варианта. На новых версиях рекомендуется использовать list, но для совместимости со старыми версиями приходится использовать List из typing.

Хорошо, спасибо. У меня в интерпретаторе и вскоде версия 3.12

@computerman судя по ошибке - нет, какой-то старой версией запускаете.
